# MATLAB style griddedInterpolant usage from Interpolations.jl

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, interpolation, julia

I'm trying to convert a MATLAB program of mine to Julia. A key feature of this program uses the `griddedInterpolant` function in MATLAB. I have found the Julia replacement (Interpolations.jl) and I have done a simple test in the 2-dimensional case to be sure that I understand how it works. This particular program uses 4-D arrays though, and I can't seem to figure out how to work the Interpolations.jl method beyond 2 dimensions.

A very simplified example of the MATLAB behavior. Note that this is a trivial example because `V` is flat, but you get the point. What my program would do is be changing the values of `V`, `kp1gv`, and `kp2gv` within a loop.

```
nK_1 = 50;
nK_2 = 50;
nKP_1 = 10;
nKP_2 = 10;
K1 = linspace(0,100,nK_1);
K2 = linspace(0,100,nK_2);
KP1 = linspace(0,100,nKP_1);
KP2 = linspace(0,100,nKP_1);

nX = 3;
nY = 3;
X = [0.9,1,1.1];
Y = [0.95,1,1.05];

[k1gv,k2gv,xgv,ygv] = ndgrid(K1,K2,X,Y);  % creates grid vectors
V = ones(nK_1,nK_2,nX,nY);    % value func to be interpolated
Fit = griddedInterpolant(k1gv,k2gv,xgv,ygv,V,'linear');   % fitted val fun


[kp1gv,kp2gv,xpgv,ypgv,kk1,kk2] = ndgrid(KP1,KP2,X,Y,K1,K2);
Fitted = Fit(kp1gv,kp2gv,xpgv,ypgv);
```

What I am looking for is to duplicate this in Julia, either exactly as it is in MATLAB or by rewriting it to be faster. Here is my attempt now:

```
nK_1 = 50
nK_2 = 50
nKP_1 = 10
nKP_2 = 10
K1 = linspace(0,100,nK_1)
K2 = linspace(0,100,nK_2)
KP1 = linspace(0,100,nKP_1)
KP2 = linspace(0,100,nKP_1)

nX = 3
nY = 3
X = [0.9,1,1.1]
Y = [0.95,1,1.05]

V = ones(nK_1,nK_2,nX,nY)

# using the more compact notation here, would be similar to
# griddedInterpolant({K1,K2,X,Y},V,'linear') -- no issues with this fit
Fit = interpolate((K1,K2,X,Y),V,Gridded(Linear()))

# this is how I'm getting ndgrid functionality
KP1gv = Float64[i for i in KP1, j in KP2, x in X, y in Y, a in K1, b in K2]
KP2gv = Float64[j for i in KP1, j in KP2, x in X, y in Y, a in K1, b in K2]
Xgv = Float64[x for i in KP1, j in KP2, x in X, y in Y, a in K1, b in K2]
Ygv = Float64[y for i in KP1, j in KP2, x in X, y in Y, a in K1, b in K2]

# what I want to work
Fitted = Fit[KP1gv,KP2gv,Xgv,Ygv]
```

I've read the documentation on Interpolations.jl, and I know this should be doable, I just can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than construct all those `ndgrid` coordinate arrays, just do this:

```
fitted = [Fit[i,j,k,l] for i in KP1, j in KP2, k in X, l in Y]
```

But a couple of tips:

- Anything performance-critical (like the line above) should be placed in a function. This is absolutely crucial. See the [performance tips](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/performance-tips/) page of the manual.
- This seems not to be well-documented, but `Gridded` is designed for cases where you have a rectangular grid, but where the spacing may not be regular. In cases of regular spacing, you can do better with

  itp = interpolate(V, Linear(), OnGrid())
  sitp = scale(itp, K1, K2, x, y)

where `x` and `y` are also `linspace` objects.

Comment: I do need the grid vectors (only for KP1 and KP2) in my actual implementation, unfortunately. Essentially, I've already done the "dimension explosion" step, but the interpolation object tries to do it for me.

Comment: Then just pass 1d vectors as your knots.